# Ordinary differential equation $y'(t)=\sin(f(t,y))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

One whose solution never makes me happy is the following:
$$y'(t)=\sin(y+t)\text{.}$$
I would start by substituting $z(t)=y(t)+t$ to get an ODE in $z(t)$, but then I'm not sure about how to substitute back my solution to check if it's correct or not$\dots$

Comment: First things first.  What have you done so far?  Have you actually gotten a potential solution to test?

Comment: I had found:
$$y(t)=2\cdot\tan^{-1}\left(-1-\frac{2}{t+c}\right)-t$$
but the more I watch it, the more I am not sure$\dots$

Comment: Have a look at Polyanin-Zaitsev's handbook on exact solutions for ODEs. Equation 20 in page 224 may be useful for you. (HTH) P.S.: I had not seen that somebody already solved the problem. This comment is no longer necessary but I am leaving it here for future reference to PZ's book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, now that you've got a solution, let's test it.  Starting with the right side, we have

$$\sin(y+t)=\sin[2\tan^{-1}(-1-\frac2{t+c})]=2\sin[\tan^{-1}(-1-\frac2{t+c})]\cos[\tan^{-1}(-1-\frac2{t+c})]=$$
$$2\tan[\tan^{-1}(-1-\frac2{t+c})]\cos^2[\tan^{-1}(-1-\frac2{t+c})]=$$
$$\dfrac{2\tan[\tan^{-1}(-1-\frac2{t+c})]}{1+\tan^2[\tan^{-1}(-1-\frac2{t+c})]}=\dfrac{-2-\frac4{t+c}}{1+(-1-\frac2{t+c})^2}=-\dfrac{2+\frac4{t+c}}{2+\frac4{t+c}+\frac4{(t+c)^2}}$$

Now let's work with the left side

$$y'=\frac d{dt}[2\tan^{-1}(-1-\frac2{t+c})-t]=\dfrac{\frac4{(t+c)^2}}{1+(-1-\frac2{t+c})^2}-\dfrac{1+(-1-\frac2{t+c})^2}{1+(-1-\frac2{t+c})^2}=$$
$$\dfrac{\frac4{(t+c)^2}-2-\frac4{t+c}-\frac4{(t+c)^2}}{2+\frac4{t+c}+\frac4{(t+c)^2}}=-\dfrac{2+\frac4{t+c}}{2+\frac4{t+c}+\frac4{(t+c)^2}}$$

It was a lot of work, but it appears your answer checks.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed substitution transforms the ODE to
$$z'(t)-1=\sin z(t), $$
which can be solved by separation of variables:
$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1+\sin z}=\int \mathrm{d}t.$$
You should get $$\frac{2}{\cot (z/2)+1}=t+c, $$
which simplifies to 
$$z= 2 \text{ arccot } \left(\frac{2}{t+c}-1 \right). $$
Finally since $y=z-t$ the general solution to the original equation is
$$ y=2 \text{ arccot } \left(\frac{2}{t+c}-1 \right)-t.$$

Comment: Ok, so there was "only" a wrong sign $-$ in my solution, thanks for the complete solution to confront!

Comment: Also $\tan^{-1}$ was wrong in my solution, $\cot^{-1}$ or $\text{arccot}$ is correct ;-)

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks to [Giuseppe Negro](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8157/giuseppe-negro))

A.D. Polyanin and  V.F. Zaitsev, in *Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations*, 2nd ed. 2003, state (equation 20, p. 201):

> $y'_x=f(x)\sin(\lambda y+g(x))$.
>
> The substituion $w=\lambda y+g(x)$ leads to an equation of the form [$\ldots$]: $w'_x=\lambda f(x)\sin(w)+g'_x(x)$.

The latter may be further reduced to a Riccati equation (see equation 11, p. 201), but in this case $f(x)\equiv 1$, $\lambda=1$ and $g(x)=\mathrm{Id}(x)$, the equation is separable and integration leads to the solution
$${y=2\text{arccot}\left(\frac{2}{t+c}-1\right)-t}\ ,\quad{c\in\mathbb{R}}$$
already agreed.

---

**Addendum:**

Last but not least, thanks to [Mike](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/17976/mike):

$$\sin(y+t)=
\sin\left[2\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)\right]=
2\sin\left[\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)\right]\cos\left[\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)\right]$$

$$=2\sin^2\left[\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)\right]\cot\left[\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)\right]=$$

$$=\dfrac{2\cot\left[\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)\right]}{1+\cot^2\left[\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)\right]}=
\dfrac{-2+\dfrac4{t+c}}{1+\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)^2}=
\dfrac{-2+\dfrac4{t+c}}{2-\dfrac4{t+c}+\dfrac4{\left(t+c\right)^2}}$$

and

$$y'=\dfrac d{dt}\left[2\cot^{-1}\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)-t\right]=
\dfrac{\dfrac4{\left(t+c\right)^2}}{1+\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)^2}-\dfrac{1+\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)^2}{1+\left(\dfrac2{t+c}-1\right)^2}=$$

$$=\dfrac{\dfrac4{\left(t+c\right)^2}-2+\dfrac4{t+c}-\dfrac4{\left(t+c\right)^2}}{2-\dfrac4{t+c}+\dfrac4{\left(t+c\right)^2}}=
\dfrac{-2+\dfrac4{t+c}}{2-\dfrac4{t+c}+\dfrac4{\left(t+c\right)^2}}$$

We did it!